# Sending HTTP request in VBA

Tags: php, vba, http

I'm using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` object to send HTTP request to my server in VBA. Here's my code:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://localhost/data.php"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencode"
objHTTP.send ("name=blabla&data=test")
```

My problem is that my data.php, which is simply:

```
var_dump($_POST['name']);
```

returns "index undefined" error. I can't access any value of my parameters. Weird part is that this code:

```
var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

returns `name=blabla&data=test` as a string. But in this case I would have to parse the data manually and I really, really don't want to do that. Why the data is not accessible via $_POST?

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencode` appears to be missing final `d`

Comment: @RamRaider OMG thank you! I've spent like 2 days debugging it and it was simply typo...

Comment: :) good news! Glad it's sorted